# Add log files to slim framework

Tags: php, slim

I am completelly new to Slim. I have used php for the last 3-4 years but I have always done everything from scratch. I want to learn this frameworks for some rest services I have to do.

I have followed a tutorial on the slim webpage to get a simple rest service working but I want to add a log system to see what is happening when something goes wrong or wathever.

This is what I have right know:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
require '../Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::requisterAutoloader();

$application = new \Slim\App();
$logger = $application->log;
$logger->setEnabled(true);
$logger->setLevel(\Slim\Log::DEBUG);

$application->get(
  '/hello/user',
  function ()
  {
    GLOBAL $logger;
    $logger->info("starting the handling function");
    echo "<data>response</data>";
    $logger->info("ending handling function");
  });

$application->run();
?>
```

I also tried with monolog but I didn't get it working.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';


$logger = new \Flynsarmy\SlimMonolog\Log\MonologWriter(array(
    'handlers' => array(
        new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('./logs/'.date('Y-m-d').'.log'),
    ),
));

$app = new Slim\App(array(
 'log.writer' => $logger,
));


$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
    //$app->log->writer("hola");
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");
    return $response;
    });
    $app->run();
```

What I would really want is to have a daily log with warnings, debug, info... in the same file. Changing the file every day.

Comment: What version of slim are you trying to use. You appear to be trying to combine but slim 3 and 2 code.

Comment: Log file is writable by web-server?

Comment: I am using 3.8. I think it is the latest one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [slim-skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/slim-skeleton) application shows how to integrate monolog.

1. Register the logger with the DI container:

   ```
   $container['logger'] = function ($c) {
       $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
       $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('test-app');
       $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
       return $logger;
   };
   ```
2. Use it in your closure:

   ```
   $app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response){
       $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
       $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
       $this->get('logger')->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");
       return $response;
   });
   ```

The logs will out output to stdout, so you'll see the in your apache error log or if you're using the built-in PHP server, in the terminal.